# Scala + Play Framework: Action composition explanation needed

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

This is the action composition taken from a sample that comes with the Play Framework

```
def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
    Action(request => f(user)(request))
  }
```

So, `Security.Authenticated` takes an `username: RequestHeader => Option[String]` and `onAuthorized: RequestHeader=>SimpleResult`and the second group of parantheses take `String => Action[A]`

And then in the controller I have:

```
def index = isAuthenticated { ...code }}
```

The code above is this, so I assume this is the `f` function `=> String => Request[AnyContent] => Result`. Now, what I don't understand is what really happens here. I am not talking about `User.findByEmail....`, I'm talking about `username => _ => ...`. What would the signature of this function look like if I called it directly?

```
username => _ =>
    User.findByEmail(username).map { user =>
      Ok(
        html.dashboard(
          Project.findInvolving(username), 
          Task.findTodoInvolving(username), 
          user
        )
      )
    }.getOrElse(Forbidden)
```

If there was `def isAuthenticated(f: => Request[AnyContent] => Result)` I'd know how to use it and I'd understand it. But the extra "data" is confusing me.

UPDATE:

I guess I found something:

```
def f2: String => Int => List[Char] = x => _ => x.toList
```

And this would be called as:

```
f2("Andrew")(2) //there can be anything replacing 2 because I don't have access to it anyway
```

So the function above that I asked primarily about would be:

```
def f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result = username => _ => User.find.....
```

Am I right?
I get a "No by name parameter allowed here error".

If they don't use the second parameter why are they using `String => Request => Result` and not just simply `String => Result`?

Comment: Maybe sometimes you need this second parameter: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/scala/zentasks/app/controllers/Projects.scala#L38

Answer (score 1):

That function definition is actually a curried function definition.

`String => Request => Result` actually means: `f(s:String):(r:Request)=>Result` ie a function that takes a String and returns a **function** that takes a Request and returns a Result.

Check out the part "Spicing up your functions": http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/30/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-11-currying-and-partially-applied-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

For me, the examples at https://github.com/mariussoutier/PlayBasics/tree/master/play-2.2-migration are very enlightening.